# Send Object To Origin

Tags: animation, 3d-manipulator, origin

What is the shortest way (or a shortcut key if there is any) to move the object to the origin?

Comment: Press `Alt`+`G`

Answer (score 3):

To reset the location of a moved object, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.
However, if you want to move a part of an object to the objects origin, select this part in edit mode and set the `Median` Values in the right toolbar to `0`.